# VBA Conditional If Then Variable modification

Tags: forms, excel, vba, checkbox

I am trying to link together information from a user input form using a "_" and conditionally Minusing one from the second variable.  Here is what i have:

```
If strckbx = True & strmonth = "oct" Then
 Range("C1") = strmonth + "_" + (strfiscalyear - 1)
 Else
 Range("C1") = strmonth + ("_") + strfiscalyear
End If

If strckbx = True & strmonth = "Nov" Then
 Range("C1") = strmonth + ("_") + (strfiscalyear- 1)
 Else
 Range("C1") = strmonth + ("_") + strfiscalyear
End If

If strckbx = True & strmonth = "dec" Then
 Range("C1") = strmonth + ("_") + (strfiscalyear - 1)
 Else
 Range("C1") = strmonth + ("_") + strfiscalyear
End If
```

The minus one is conditional on a check box in the user form.  When i try to run or test it i keep getting a runtime error 13: type mismatch.  Anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `And` and not `&`.

e.g.

```
If strckbx = True And strmonth = "oct" Then
```

`&` is used for concatenation in VBA.

Read more here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot subtract a number from a string. That will give you a type mismatch.

Do this instead: `cstr(cint(strfiscalyear) - 1)`

Also, consider using `And` in place of `&`

Comment: Range("C1") = strmonth & "_" & (strfiscalyear) - 1